# How to format output using cout

Tags: c++

I am aware that it is likely possible to do this using some other method such as printf(), but I want to know if this can be done using cout.

```
Insert -8:   -8 90 34 -78 34 235 9 -12 653
Insert -78:  -78 -8 34 90 34 235 9 -12 653
```

This is partial output from a sorting algorithm. It is showing what happens after each pass. Each number is from the same vector. How is it possible to have the minus signs always align for the first element as shown above (elements after that don't matter)?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
cout << "Insert " << my_vector[pos] << ": ";

for (int k = 0; k < size_of_vector; k++) {
  cout << my_vector[k] << " ";
}

cout << endl;
```

However, my code results in output that looks like this:

```
Insert -8: -8 90 34 -78 34 235 9 -12 653 
Insert -78: -78 -8 34 90 34 235 9 -12 653
```

Comment: Check [`setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`right()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

Comment: Output CSV and use a spreadsheet program to display it. Otherwise, what you want is impossible: Without knowing the size of the largest number, you can't align them, so you would have to know all output in advance. As a workaround, you might be able to reserve enough for every column using `setw()`.

Comment: Let me clarify, I don't want each number aligned, just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to output the lead-in as a single string, in a specified field width, e.g.

```
cout
    << "Insert "
    << setw( 14 ) << to_string( my_vector[pos] ) + ":";
```

The magic number needs to be chosen to accomodate the maximum number of digits and sign.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

Comment: This won't compile unless I use "g++ -std=c++0x", which is more of an inconvenience than the misalignment.

Comment: @FlashDrive: use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` with g++. There is no good reason I can think to code for a 12 year old standard when there are two newer standards. Note that you can change the default for g++ by creating your own specs file (use option `-dumpspecs` to create initial one).

Comment: That said, if you are the victim of a silly & incompetent teacher who requires you to adhere to C++03, then simply code up a `to_string` function. Or do it directly at the place.